# HTML5 download links not working

Tags: html, download, href

I've made a snazzy first website, but I can't get the download links to work without manually opening them in a new tab on my browser. I've tried using different browsers, setting `target="_blank"` and fiddling with the `download` property in the `<a>` tag, to no avail. What on earth is happening?

Here's [my website](http://www.cbio.uct.ac.za/~arjun/).

Comment: It works fine if you disable JavaScript, so figure out what part of `script.js` is causing your click event to either stop propagating or get prevented.

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my twitter bootstrap css files were outdated. After an update, links worked again!